# executing a batch command through SSIS Job

Tags: ssis

I need to execute an batch file through SSIS job. previously we used to do this in cmd prompt, is there any way that we can run batch file through ssis job

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use an `Execute Process Task` in your Control Flow to do this.

- Create a new package in SSIS
- You will start with the Control Flow open
- Drag an `Execute Process Task` from the Toolbox (if the Toolbox is not open, open it with `Menu` -> `View` -> `Toolbox`) to the Control Flow
- You can set the batch file path in `RightMouseButton on the Task` -> `Edit...` -> `Process` -> `Executable`

For further instructions on SSIS go to e.g. [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966389.aspx)

Comment: HI Ocaso: Am completely new to this process, if u dont mind can u eloborate on this, or provide me an example.

Comment: Edit: Added some more explanation

Comment: Thanks very much Ocaso and Robbie, for giving me valuable info. Thanks  a lot

Comment: It works great on the server using VS. When I run it through a SQL agent, I get an error with code `0xC0029151`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Hmm, maybe try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786748/executing-ssis-package-as-sqlagent-job If that doesn't help search SO for that error code and/or post a new question.

Comment: @OcasoProtal Thanks for the response. I already have that in place. I will open a new question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, consider if you really need to execute a batch file. Maybe there is a built in way to achieve what you need. For example if you are just moving/renaming files then you can [use the FileSystemTask](http://www.rafael-salas.com/2007/03/ssis-file-system-task-move-and-rename.html)

Otherwise, you can use the [ExecuteProcessTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141166%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

- [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178485%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) shows all the options that can be configured for this task, i.e. the path to the batch file, arguments, etc.
- [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139733%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) shows how to set those properties.