# SSIS Package and Bat file

Tags: sql-server

How can I run a Stored Package with a .bat file? I am running it locally on a server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [executing a batch command through SSIS Job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770851/executing-a-batch-command-through-ssis-job)

Comment: @dfundako The answer doesn't seem complete to me.

Comment: @dfundako  I need to know how to write the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a package from the command line, use the [DTExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) tool.  The location of DTExec depends on the version of SQL you have installed.  Assuming you have SQL Server 2008 R2, you could save the following text to a file with a .bat extension somewhere on your SQL server.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "D:\PathTo\MyPackage.dtsx"
```

Double click the the .bat file to execute the command above.
Here is [more information](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/126293/) on DTExec and BAT files.