# MD5 : Generate excel's files

Tags: sql, ssis, md5

How do i generate MD5 hash of excel files ?

I got bunch of files , and i have to create hash for one of them .

Like example bellow

```
File            Hash 
File1.xls       1892assaehas1873123128asehsa
File2.xls       jkshae8912739bnmbxzvm871931bxz
```

Im working on SISS and probably i got to create a Script Component on my Solution like C# or VBA .

Anyone has suggestion to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "Execute Process Task" can be used to run a .bat file script. The file produced is a CSV (Comma Separated Variable) file.

=== genhash.bat

```
@echo off
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.xlsx' | ForEach-Object {" ^
        "$hash = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path $_.FullName).Hash;" ^
        "$nfn = $_.FullName + '.md5';" ^
        "'{0},{1}' -f @($_.FullName, $hash) | Out-File -FilePath $nfn -Encoding ascii;" ^
    "}"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770913/447901

Answer (score 1):

You should not use MD5 - it has known collisions and there are free websites online that can provide the value that is hashed. You should consider using more modern hashing algorithms that do not yet have known collisions, such as; SHA or B-Crypt.

- https://md5decrypt.net/en/
- https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker/MD5
- https://www.md5online.org/md5-decrypt.html
- https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is SISS but there are several examples of generating md5 for files:
[example 1 (C#)](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2018/04/calculate-hash-codes-for-a-file-in-c/),
[example 2](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/crypto.html#MD5). excel files are the same as any other file. you read bytes, insert into the hash function and digest the result