# Microsoft SQL Agent Job cannot execute SSIS Package with Embedded C#

Tags: c#, ssis, jobs, agent

Hi I'm hoping someone can help me as I have spent the best part of a day trying to get this to work, and I apologise for the length of the question.

I am using SQL server 2012 and have a SSIS Package written in Visual Studio 2010 that consists of a C# Script Task that invokes an API and collects data from a website and inserts it into a SQL data table.

This works fine without any issues when executing the package from Visual Studio and if I import the dtsx into the msdb database in Integration Services or import into the File System.

The problem only arises when I try to execute the job via a SQL Agent Job, I have tried everything I can find online and to the best of my knowledge but still the job fails to execute.

Below is a list of things I have tried, in each case I get the error "The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)"

The package was written by one of our developers and then checked into version control then opened by myself.

1. Set the various ProtectionLevels within Visual Studio of the package and tried to execute even with a password, this fails to execute.
2. Opened the package on the server that I am trying to execute from and even logged in as the service account I am running under and then re saved the package.
3. Tried to execute the package from the File System, msdb, tried simply calling a batch file that uses dtexec (which executes fine locally within command prompt)
4. Tried executing as a PowerShell command both using code within the agent job or calling a script
5. Created a new local admin account on the server and added this as a SQL Login then created a Credential and a proxy, this didn't work
6. Tried a different proxy account that has the same access as myself, this failed.
7. Tried to create a stored procedure and execute from there but the same error appears.
8. There are no connection managers within the SSIS Package, I have granted the folders on the server with the permissions so that the agent job can see the dtsx file.
9. Set the SISS package to 32 bit and the Agent Job to 32 bit runtime.

I have exhausted every option I can try but for some reason the SSIS package will only execute via a SQL Agent Job if I create a Credential and a Proxy and point this to my Windows login credentials and then run the Agent Job as this Proxy account.

Whatever I change still allows me to execute within Visual Studio and if I Run Package by right clicking on it within Integration Services.

Is there something I am missing? Can you not run a SSIS Package with embedded C# from an Agent Job as I have written many packages before and executed them without any issues until this particular one.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786748/executing-ssis-package-as-sqlagent-job

Comment: I have tried to execute the job in both 32 and 64 bit by setting the SSIS package to 32 bit and the Agent Job to 32 bit runtime also.

Comment: "The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE" is insufficient error data. Edit your job step to add the `/REP EWI` under the advanced tab. Pull back the full results of your package execution.

Comment: Has the package ever run successfully outside SQL Agent on the same server you are attempting to run the package? RDP into said machine and execute the package like `dtexec /file MyPackage /rep EWI` or lookup the syntax for calling a package stored in the MSDB. You need to spec server and path to the package.

Comment: To directly answer the question posed, Yes, SQL Agent can run an SSIS package with embedded C#. Generally, when code doesn't run on servers, it has been my experience someone is referencing a library/dll that is not installed on the server (needs to be in the GAC)

Comment: Hi billinkc thanks for your reply, the package has run successfully on the server if I log on as myself, if I log on to the server as any other user this fails, even if they have the same permissions as myself. It's bizarre how no matter how I execute the package as my user it is fine, but as soon as any others are used it fails. It's as though my credentials are embedded somewhere in the package, but where I don't know as there are no connection managers and even when I save the package under a different user it still fails as them.

Comment: Be sure to use the @ with my handle, otherwise you have to hope I check old questions ;) What does the script task/component look like? Can you post the code? My guess based on the current detail is that you have a permission issue but whether it's the account running the SSIS package, the account being presented to the web api, possibly a firewall thing is rather hard to say at the moment

Comment: Hi @billinkc we have decided to pass the API collection over to the web dev team so that they can create a service and write this completely in C# to collect the data. This way it is managed by the web team. We couldn't get the Agent job to work at all, we had gone through all permissions that we could but perhaps there was something we were missing. I have created other jobs with C# in them with no problem so it must have been something with the API. Thanks for your help on this.